# how can i properly upgrade bootstrap in laravel 5.6?

Tags: composer-php, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.6

i'm currently use laravel 5.6 with an old version of bootstrap.

in the bootstrap.min.css i have this line:

> /*!* Bootstrap v2.3.0** Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc*

also bootstrap-responsive telling me

> Bootstrap Responsive v2.3.0

how can I update the bootstrap version from 2 to 4?

Comment: It depends on how you're pulling the Bootstrap framework in. Laravel 5.6 comes with a package.json that should pull in BS4 for you and just need loading and processing.

Comment: If you just want to update the single file, then follow the instructions here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/

Comment: alright then! Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 — Remove existing bootstrap

Uninstall Bootstrap

```
npm uninstall --save-dev bootstrap-sass
```

Step 2 — Install Bootstrap 4

Install Bootstrap 4 beta and popperjs

```
npm install --save-dev bootstrap@^4.0.0-beta.2 popper.js
```

Step 3 — Update code references

**In resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js** replace

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}
```

with

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

In **resources/assets/sass/app.scss** replace

```
@import “~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap”
```

with

```
@import “~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss”
```

In **resources/assets/sass/_variable.scss** replace

```
$font-size-base: 14px;
```

with

```
$font-size-base: 0.875rem;
```

Step 4 — Recompile Assets

Run

```
npm run dev
```

Now you have removed all Bootstrap 3 references and installed Bootstrap 4